# Microsoft Bot with LUIS not detecting newly created intents

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I created a web app bot using the LUIS template on Azure. The bot reaches the default intents created (Greeting, Help, Cancel and None), but gives a "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" error message when I invoke newly created intents in LUIS.

The newly created intents are reached successfully using the LUIS Test platform and when I query the LUIS endpoint, so it seems the issue is from the bot.

I can't figure out what's causing this issue.

Comment: Have to trained and published LUIS after changes?

Comment: yes, turns out I have to  manually define the handlers for the newly created intents under the BasicLuisDialog.cs, thought the publish takes care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to manually define the handlers for the newly created intents under the BasicLuisDialog.cs, thought the publish takes care of this.

Comment: You can also define a default luis intent with [LuisIntent("")] in your BasicLuisDialog.cs to prevent getting the "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" which will catch new intents that aren't in your dialog.